# Form action not going to right php page

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I created form in modal, but when submitting form, it doesn't go to the right page, where it should go, which is in this case, edithw.php.

Here is content of modal:

```
$dialogContent = "      <div class=\"modal-header\">
                <h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"editModalLabel\">Muokkaa Läksy</h4>
            </div>
            <div class=\"modal-body\">
                <form action='https://developerfromjokela.com/homework/web/edithw.php' method=\"post\">
                    <div class=\"form-group\">
                        <label for=\"hwtitle\">Läksyn otsikko</label>
                        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"hwtitle\" id=\"hwtitle\" placeholder=\"Biologian läksy...\" value=\"$name\"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class=\"form-group\">
                        <label for=\"hwdetails\">Läksyn tiedot</label>
                        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"hwdetails\" id=\"hwdetails\" placeholder=\"Sivu 12 tehtävä 1 luettavaksi...\" value=\"$details\"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class=\"form-group\">
                        <label class=\"label-control\">Palautuspäivä</label>
                        <input type=\"date\" name=\"hwdonedate\" value=\"$donedate\"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='visibility: hidden;'>
                    <input type='text' name='hwid' value='$hwid'/>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                       <label class=\"mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect\" for=\"checkbox-1\">
                          <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox-1\" name=\"done\" value=\"1\" class=\"mdl-checkbox__input\" $checked />
                           <span class=\"mdl-checkbox__label\">Tehty</span>
                        </label>


                    <input type=\"submit\" name='submit' class=\"btn btn-primary\" value='Tallenna'/>
                    <a href='memberpage.php' class='btn btn-primary'>Takaisin</a>
                    </form>
            </div>";
```

The whole code is in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/JTr9pVmC

edithw.php:

```
 <?php require('includes/config.php');
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); exit(); }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM homeworks WHERE homeworkID = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['hwid']));
    $row2save = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
    $username = $row2save['owner'];
    if ($username === $_SESSION['username']) {
        $done = 0;
        if ($_POST['done'] === 1) {
            $done = 1;
        }
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE homeworks
      SET name = :name, details = :details, donedate = :donedate, done = :done
      WHERE homeworkID = :id');
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['hwid'], ':name' => $_POST['hwtitle'], ':details' => $_POST['hwdetails'], ':donedate' => $_POST['hwdonedate'], ':done' => $done));
    } else {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name('USERNAME'),'RESTRICTED',1,
            isset($params['path']),
            isset($params['domain']),
            isset($params['secure']),
            isset($params['httponly']));
        header('Location: memberpage.php?restricted='.$row2save['owner']);

    }
} else {
    echo 'Error! No form inputs found!';
}
?>
```

Why might this be happening? I changed early action from edithw.php to full URL, hoping that maybe fix the problem, but it didn't.

**Note**: Form is going nowhere, staying on memberpage.php which have submit also, and it's used to add homeworks to database. edithw.php is for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that on other modal from tag was not closed, so new form tag cannot be made.

By adding `</form>` to the `exampleModal`, I fixed problem.

I just find out that the tag was missing accidentally.